# How to generate a time series data for a month with a gap of 1 second using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am generating dates between 01-01-2010 and 31-01-2010 with a gap of  1 second as follows:

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 31, 23, 59, 59)
step = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)

result = []

while dt < end:
    result.append(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    dt += step
```

and the result that it gives it perfectly fine, but it takes about 10secs to give the result.

I was wondering if the same can be achieved using pandas so that it can be achieved a bit quickly

Comment: `pd.date_range('1 Jan 2010','2010-01-30 23:59:59',freq='S')` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
result = pd.date_range(dt, end, freq='S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tolist()
```

Or:

```
result = pd.date_range('2010-01-01',
                       '2010-01-30 23:59:59',freq='S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tolist()
```

Comment: Hey @jezrael, thanks for the help. I have a query: I tried running your code and the code suggested by anky in the comments and the code suggested by you takes about 20secs to run but the code suggested by anky just takes about 1sec. Do you know why is there such a large difference?

Comment: @Junkrat - hmmm, in comments are not datetimes converted to strings by `strftime`, so it is difference.

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
l = (pd.DataFrame(columns=['NULL'],
                  index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01T00:00:00Z', '2010-01-31T00:00:00Z',
                                      freq='1T'))

       .index.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
       .tolist()
)

print(l)
```